# Error en Terminal Atom

Tags: python, terminal, packages

que tal?

Entré a Atom hoy en mi trabajo y no logré abrir la terminal. 
Siempre tenía el símbolo de + abajo a la izquierda para abrir la terminal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No aparece el botón para abrir la terminal y me aparece este error cuando quiero instalar de nuevo la terminal,

Alguien sabe por que pasa esto? o alguien le paso algo parecido? 
Gracias por la ayuda

Saludos,

Comment: aparece en el mensaje que no encuentra el ejecutable de python. Actualizaste algo?

Comment: Lo único que hice después de darme cuenta que no tenía la terminal fue descargar la última versión de Python y instalarla, nada más